# flooding the views with update requests issue in observer pattern(C++)

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, observer-pattern

I have some MVC code, it uses the observer mode, such as below:

```
void Model::ChangeMethod1()
{
    m_A = m_A + 1;
    ...
    Notify();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod2()
{
    m_A = m_A + 2;
    ...
    Notify();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod3()
{
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
    Notify();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod4()
{
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
    ChangeMethod3();
    Notify();
}
```

There are many functions like `ChangeMethodX` which will make changes to the Model, and notify the viewers, and when the viewers receive the events, they will refresh/update themselves.

You see, each function `ChangeMethodX` has a Notify() function, which internally send an event to the observer.

But I don't want the observer receive too many events in the each function, because there will too many events, I would like each top level function call whether it has any internal function calls only send one update event to the viewer.

I think this is a very common issue that happens in many situations, such as the MVC mode, as a model will notify viewers to get updated. But we have to avoid the flooded events if the model changes several times inside a top level function call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought of 2 possible approaches:

If the subject is completely under your control and this solution is not too invasive, you could add an optional parameter specifying whether the called `ChangeMethodX` is a top level function, like this:

```
void Model::ChangeMethod1(bool topLevel = true)
{
    m_A = m_A + 1;
    ...
    NotifyIfTopLevel(topLevel);
}

void Model::ChangeMethod2(bool topLevel = true)
{
    m_A = m_A + 2;
    ...
    NotifyIfTopLevel(topLevel);
}

void Model::ChangeMethod3(bool topLevel = true)
{
    ChangeMethod1(false);
    ChangeMethod2(false);
    NotifyIfTopLevel(topLevel);
}

void Model::ChangeMethod4(bool topLevel = true)
{
    ChangeMethod1(false);
    ChangeMethod2(false);
    ChangeMethod3(false);
    NotifyIfTopLevel(topLevel);
}

void Model::NotifyIfTopLevel(bool topLevel)
{
    if (topLevel)
        Notify();
}
```

However, it is ugly most of the time and it could dirty your interface.

---

The second approach you could choose is on the other hand risky if you have to deal with concurrency. Moreover if you catch an exception and you handle it, you must remember to bring the object back in a correct state (`is_changing--` if not called yet), otherwise the observers are not going to receive notifications anymore.

```
int is_changing = 0;

void Model::ChangeMethod1()
{
    m_A = m_A + 1;
    ...
    NotifyIfNotChanging();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod2()
{
    m_A = m_A + 2;
    ...
    NotifyIfNotChanging();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod3()
{
    is_changing++;
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
    is_changing--;
    NotifyIfNotChanging();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod4()
{
    is_changing++;
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
    ChangeMethod3();
    is_changing--;
    NotifyIfNotChanging();
}

void Model::NotifyIfNotChanging()
{
    if (is_changing == 0)
        Notify();
}
```

If you have that many `ChangeMethodX` methods, maybe consider using an Aspect Oriented framework to separate the concern of notifying observers. Especially if you need to repeat `is_changing++`/`--` or trivially the `Notify` call, moving them in the appropriate aspect class would definitely be more readable.

---

**EDIT**

As for the RAII approach, it is in my opinion kind of overused here since you do not have resources to release, creating and disposing objects every time is quite overkilling for your needs.
By the way, if you want to follow this path, then I recommend you to fix some code smells.

1. You are not encapsulating appropriately the `SetTopLevelCall`. It is not supposed to be `public` because the user of your class must not mess with it.
2. There is a new public class `DeferredEventSender` that is tightly coupled to your `Model` class. The worst part is that it is responsible for the `Notify` method, that should be called by the `Model` itself. Moreover, you are ruling out the possibility to need to access the `Model` private fields and functions.

Here is how I would face these issues, even though it is not perfect yet.

```
class Model
{
    public:
        Model()
        {
        }
    
        ~Model()
        {
        }
    
        void ChangeMethod1();
        void ChangeMethod2();
        void ChangeMethod3();
        void ChangeMethod4();
    
        void Notify();
    
    protected:
    
        class DeferredEventSender
        {
            public:
            
                DeferredEventSender(Model* m)
                {
                    _m = m;
                    doCallNotify = _m->topLevel;
                    _m->topLevel = false;
                }
            
                ~DeferredEventSender()
                {
                    if (doCallNotify)
                    {
                        _m->Notify();
                        _m->topLevel = true;
                    }
                }
                
                Model* _m;
                bool doCallNotify;
        };
    
        bool topLevel = true;
    
        int m_A;
        int m_B;
};


void Model::ChangeMethod1()
{
    Model::DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    m_A = m_A + 1;
}

...
```

Comment: Thanks. About the second approach, I'm thing something like RAII, which means I need to track all the call-stack of every function, if an inner function knows it has called from a toplevel function(like we need a locker in toplevel function call), then the inner function will not send the event, we can send an event in the destructor of the locker. Something like this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/66417/generic-logging-class-for-tracing-the-function-calls.  I am not familiar with the term `Aspect Oriented framework`, any good resource about this framework for C++?

Comment: @ollydbg23 I have never used it but the only AOP framework for C++ I have heard of is AspectC++. Maybe I got it wrong, but if you want to wrap the `Notify` method in a RAII-based mechanism, pay attention because if you have that many events, it could slow down your application. it is certainly convenient in some situation, but you should not abuse it, especially if an increasing/decreasing integer is enough for your needs. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: Hi, @Marco Luzzara, I just followed the second approach you suggested, and wrote a simple demo C++, I think I need a post another Answer here.

Comment: Hi, @Marco Luzzara, I have added my answer, you can have a look, thanks.

Comment: @ollydbg23 I made some edits too. They are just some considerations after having seen your solution, which is valid and correct of course.

Comment: Hi, @Marco Luzzara, thanks for your suggestion, I have modified my answer by adding a revision 2 code.

Answer (score 0):

I just follow Marco Luzzara's second approach, and create a simple demo C++ code, see below:

**Revision 1:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Model
{
public:
    Model()
        : m_TopLevelCallScope(false)
    {
    }

    ~Model()
    {
    }

    void ChangeMethod1();
    void ChangeMethod2();
    void ChangeMethod3();
    void ChangeMethod4();

    void Notify();

    bool IsTopLevelCall()
    {
        return m_TopLevelCallScope;
    }

    void SetTopLevelCall(bool topLevel)
    {
        m_TopLevelCallScope = topLevel;
    }

private:

    // if this variable is true, it means a top level call scope is entered
    // then all the inner call should not send event, the final event could
    // send when the top level sender get destructed
    bool m_TopLevelCallScope;

    // other members
    int m_A;
    int m_B;
};


// this is a deferred notification
// each function should create a local object
// but only the top level object can finally send a notification
class DeferredEventSender
{
public:

    DeferredEventSender(Model* model)
        : m_Model(model)
    {
        if(m_Model->IsTopLevelCall() == false)
        {
            m_Model->SetTopLevelCall(true);
            m_TopLevelCallScope = true;
        }
        else
        {
            m_TopLevelCallScope = false;
        }
    }

    ~DeferredEventSender()
    {
        if (m_TopLevelCallScope == true)
        {
            // we are exiting the top level call, so restore it to false
            // it's time to send the notification now
            m_Model->SetTopLevelCall(false);
            m_Model->Notify();
        }
        // do nothing if m_TopLevelCallScope == false
        // because this means we are in a inner function call
    }
    bool m_TopLevelCallScope;
    Model* m_Model;
};



void Model::ChangeMethod1()
{
    DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    m_A = m_A + 1;
}

void Model::ChangeMethod2()
{
    DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    m_A = m_A + 2;
}

void Model::ChangeMethod3()
{
    DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod4()
{
    DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
    ChangeMethod3();
}

void Model::Notify()
{
    cout << "Send event!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Model m;

    m.ChangeMethod1();

    m.ChangeMethod2();

    m.ChangeMethod3();

    m.ChangeMethod4();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output of the demo C++ code:

```
Send event!
Send event!
Send event!
Send event!
```

You see that in the main() function, I have only 4 function calls, and only 4 events is send.

The method I use is that I put a `DeferredEventSender` local object in each `ChangeMethodX` method, and if it is a top level function call, this object will have its member variable `m_TopLevelCallScope` set as true, if it is a inner function call, `m_TopLevelCallScope` is set as false.

When the `DeferredEventSender` local object leaves the scope, it will check to see if it is the top level object, if true, it will send the event, so all the inner function calls won't send events.

The demo code can be extended, so that events can be accumulated and stored in a `std::queue<Event>` in the `DeferredEventSender` object or `Model` object, and when the top `DeferredEventSender` object get destroyed, we can run a filter in the `std::queue<Event>`, and remove the duplicated events, and send the events we actually needed.

---

As suggested by Marco Luzzara, this is the modified version, thanks Marco Luzzara!

**Revision 2:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Model
{
    public:
        Model()
        {
        }

        ~Model()
        {
        }

        void ChangeMethod1();
        void ChangeMethod2();
        void ChangeMethod3();
        void ChangeMethod4();

        void Notify();

    protected:

        class DeferredEventSender
        {
            public:

                DeferredEventSender(Model* m)
                {
                    m_Model = m;

                    // the first instance of the DeferredEventSender will copy the status of m_TopLevel
                    // and all the later(inner) instances will have false m_TopLevel
                    m_DoCallNotify = m_Model->m_TopLevel;
                    m_Model->m_TopLevel = false;
                }

                ~DeferredEventSender()
                {
                    // we only call Notify on the top level DeferredEventSender
                    if (m_DoCallNotify)
                    {
                        m_Model->Notify();
                        m_Model->m_TopLevel = true;
                    }
                }

                Model* m_Model;
                bool m_DoCallNotify;
        };

        bool m_TopLevel = true;

        int m_A;
        int m_B;
};


void Model::ChangeMethod1()
{
    Model::DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    m_A = m_A + 1;
}

void Model::ChangeMethod2()
{
    Model::DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    m_A = m_A + 2;
}

void Model::ChangeMethod3()
{
    Model::DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
}

void Model::ChangeMethod4()
{
    Model::DeferredEventSender sender(this);
    ChangeMethod1();
    ChangeMethod2();
    ChangeMethod3();
}

void Model::Notify()
{
    cout << "Send event!" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Model m;

    m.ChangeMethod1();

    m.ChangeMethod2();

    m.ChangeMethod3();

    m.ChangeMethod4();

    return 0;
}
```